# What is the difference between Docker's "rolling" and "latest" tags?

Tags: docker, versions

On the Docker Hub site, I find tags "rolling" and "latest".
What is the difference between them?

https://hub.docker.com/_/ubuntu/

Comment: The complete explanation of both tags is on the same page you linked to. Use the "find" feature of your browser if you don't have enough time to read it all.

Answer (score 3):

`ubuntu:latest` means the latest LTS release - as of writing this comment, that would be Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. Next LTS will be Ubuntu 20.04 LTS in 2020.

`ubuntu:rolling` means the latest release regardless of LTS status - as of writing this, that would be Ubuntu 18.04 - until Ubuntu 18.10 comes out in October.

LTS is generally more stable and less likely to have features break, but also has older versions of software.

Answer (score 3):

From the linked page:

> The `ubuntu:latest` tag points to the "latest LTS", since that's the version recommended for general use. The `ubuntu:rolling` tag points to the latest release (regardless of LTS status).

The current "latest" and "rolling" release is 18.04 LTS. The next "latest" release will be 20.04 LTS; the next "rolling" release will be 18.10.